# How to add apk file as expansion file and launch from external storage directly in android?

Tags: android

1) Can I add apk file as expansion file in android.
2) I am trying to launch app directly from external storage but getting error.

code:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/devui1.example.com.testing/main.98376.devui1.example.com.testing.obb/app-debug.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

USe this code to extract or install apk programatically.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Use this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969421/1223291

It will be download apk from download manager and install automatically.